# How can I find a function's source code with PyCharm in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I cannot see the source code for the function `abs()`.

How can I find the source code with PyCharm?

[`abs()` code in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enYnY.png)

Comment: The source for that function is C code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L312

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's looking for the source code for CPython.